# Add header with token to url using Ionic inApp browser

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I’m using the Ionic inApp browser to open a URL. This is my code:

```
const target = '_self';
const browser = this.iab.create('https://example/dev/ViewForPdf');
browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
      browser.insertCSS({ code: 'body{color: red;' });
});
```

I have an authorization token that I need to pass in the header of the request, is there a way to do this?

Because right now if I open the specified URL it redirects me to the login page of the app because I’m sending the request without the token.

I also want to specify that in my project I already have an httpInterceptor that attaches the token to every http request, but for some reason when opening the URL with Ionic inApp browser it doesn’t work.
It works fine if I use the capacitor inApp browser. For example, using this line of code I can open the URL without any problem

```
await Browser.open({ url: 'https://example/dev/ViewForPdf' });
```

but unfortunately for a specific reason, I have to use the Ionic inApp browser.

I have already tried to attach the token inside the url like this (without success):

```
https://example/dev/ViewForPdf?tk=xxxx12345
```

Comment: The only solution here is to either get your company to accept that a different plug-in is required. https://www.sanketm.com/cordova-inappbrowser-custom-headers/ Or hack your back end to accept the header in the query param. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/issues/361 and

Comment: @E.Maggini unfortunately is not possible for me to use a Cordova plugin and I can't also modify the backend, so I guess I'll have to take a different road.

Comment: The Ionic inappbrowser is, in fact, a cordova plugin. As such, it should be possible to argue for a different version which provides the functionality you need. Or since the plugin is open source, fork it and add the functionality you need.